# How to redirect to a page in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to redirect the page using JSX `<Link />` tag. Here is my code:

links.js:

```
<Link to="/kategoriler" className="nav-link">
    categories
</Link>
```

App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import links from 'links';
import CategoriesPage from './components/pages/categoriesPage';

class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            
            <Router>
                <Route path = "/" component = {App}>
                    <Route path="kategoriler" component={CategoriesPage} />
                </Route>
                
            </Router>
            
        );
    }
} 


export default App;
```

It should load the `categoriesPage.js`, but it does nothing. When I go to http://localhost:3000/kategoriler it shows blank page.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I'm pretty sure the `<Link>` component should be imported from `react-router-dom` and not `react-router`
2. `<Route path="kategoriler" component={CategoriesPage} />` you did forgot the slash in the route name like this -> `<Route path="/kategoriler" component={CategoriesPage} />`, maybe you can add `exact` params in the route too ?
3. Maybe you can try to put the 2 routes next to each other instead of nesting it inside the App like this

```
<Route exact path="/" component={App} />
<Route exact path="/kategoriler" component={CategoriesPage} />
```